# is it good or bad practice to inherit viewmodel from a model class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, model-view-controller, viewmodel

if you a class (also a efcore entity):

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and say you have a viewmodel for details page:

```
class PersonViewmodel : Person
{
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

(for simplicity i have only included 1 property but there may be other properties like a selectlist etc for create/edit page)

is it a good or bad idea for the viewmodel to inherit from the model?

Comment: Seems like a recipe for accidentally exposing a raft of internal/implementation details if there ever was one..

Comment: It is not recommended. Segregate your ViewModel completely from your Model.

Answer (score 2):

It is very important to understand when it makes sense to use inheritance and to understand if you have common properties - it doesn't mean you should necessarily use inheritance. From what I understand - `Person` is a `domain` object. In this case, your view model inherits from the domain object and I can with certainty say - that is a bad pattern. View model or other kinds of DTOs should be separate from domain objects. It would make sense if your concrete `view model` would extend(sorry it's a Java definition) parent `view model`, but not a class with a different purpose. Mainly, because your Person domain object may scale in a different way from what you want to display or use on the UI, and when it scales it will immediately affect your view model because it's a base class to it.

Comment: The answer was very good, I think it is better to use inheritance when this sentence means that the `derived class` is a `base class`.